# Unanswered questions duplicated by another user

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

This question refers to this SO question: [iOS detect touchup through segue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28063769/172695). In the very first sentence, the OP declares, that it *is* a duplicate of [iOS: Detecting touch down, segue, touch up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22433887/172695), but still he opened this new question.

I consider this being not a good practice. But I also understand the intent of the OP who duplicated the question, since he cannot raise e.g. a bounty on the other one. Is there any other strategy to avoid this?

Comment: Why couldn't he raise a bounty on the other one?

Comment: @Bart nott enough reputation, not enough will to give up reputation...

Comment: 4.7k @JanDvorak. That should suffice.

Comment: then I guess he technically could...

Comment: I had the impression that only the OP can raise a bounty. So much for that, learned something new.

Comment: @SebastianDressler false...

Comment: @SebastianDressler the user now put a bounty on the other one. ;)

Comment: Now let's get the dupe deleted

Comment: @Bart so much for that.